# Thread persistence between calls

Tags: python, multithreading

I can't find a way to make my threads persistent between the first and second call of my script.

So far, when I run `python script_1.py A` the script runs the `if option == 'A'` block and starts the thread. Then, the script exits and the thread is cleaned up. So, when I run `python script_1.py B` the `isAlive` attribute can't be used.

is there any way to keep persistence?

The code for script_1.py is:

```
from script_2 import imp

script_2 = imp()
if option == 'A':
  script_2.start()
elif option == 'B':
  script_2.stop()
```

and for script_2.py is:

```
from threading import Thread

class workerThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self, _parent):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.parent = _parent
    self.active = False

  def run(self):
    while(self.active == False):
      print 'I am here'
    print 'and now I am here'

class imp():
  def __init__(self):
    self.threadObj = None

  def start(self):
    self.threadObj = workerThread(self)
    self.threadObj.start()

  def stop(self):
    if self.threadObj.isAlive() == True:
      print 'it is alive'
```

Comment: Well that's because, the thread is not alive across instances? When you run your script the first time it starts the thread alright and then dies. The second run you try to stop a non-started thread. My guess is that you run into a `None type has no attribute 'isAlive'` or something close to it? If you're coming from a C background, a thread in Python isn't **really** a thread, it's a parallel execution to your main thread object. When the main application dies the thread "dies", if you start the same script again, a new instance is borned with subthreads which others can't communicate with.

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know that. So, any solution to do what I want?

Comment: Stop using `threading` for one, secondly, check out [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) which i think might be more useful. Either that or utilize unix sockets to communicate between threads, it's the easy way out. (I've seen some experiments around where you change your execution permission to gain access to another process calls, but I've really only found glimpses of it when searching for OpenGL related stuff...)

Comment: @Torxed wouldn't multiprocessing result in the exact same problem? The problem here is that script_1.py is executed and then exits. Everything "disappears".

Comment: Maybe, or well.. come to think of it you probably will. I've only used `multiprocessing` a couple of times when i needed to use more cores and it can fork off a new instance of the application in another core but with a shared memory, so I just imagined you'd might be able to use that to do what you wanted to do :)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be:

```
from threading import Thread
from socket import *
from time import sleep
class workerThread(Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.sock = socket()
    self.sock.bind(('', 9866))
    self.sock.listen(4)
    self.start()

  def run(self):
    while 1:
      ns, na = self.sock.accept()
      if ns.recv(8192) in (b'quit', 'quit'):
        ns.close()
        break
    self.sock.close()
    print('Worker died')

imp = workerThread()
```

And the first script:

```
if option == 'A':
  from time import sleep
  from script_2 import imp
  while 1:
    sleep(0.1)
elif option == 'B':
  from socket import *
  s = socket()
  s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 9866))
  s.send('quit') # b'quit' if you're using Python3
  s.close()
```

It's not even close to elegant, but it's a 5min mockup of what you could do.
To make this closer to useable code, I'd go with:

```
self.sock = fromfd('/path/to/socket', AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM)
```

and register it with an ePoll object within the worker thread.

```
import select
self.watch = select.epoll()
self.watch.register(self.sock.fileno(), select.EPOLLIN)

while 1:
    for fd, event in self.watch.poll(0.1):
        if fd == self.sock.fileno() and event == select.EPOLLIN:
            ns, na = self.sock.accept()
            # store socket and register it
        elif event == select.EPOLLIN:
            data = storedSockets[fd].recv(8192)
            # and do work on it
```

Anyway, but you will need to keep the first instance of your execution running and create some form of communication method for the second instance you start up, i used sockets as an example which i think is rather good, especially in conjunction with unix sockets and epoll because the speed is fantastisc. You can also use [memcache](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/1.53)